# Auto align custom box / fa icon not showing

Tags: html, css, angularjs, alignment, font-awesome

I am using Angular to display a list of active sessions with their details. I want to display a custom box with some text, two boxes per row. However, I encountered some problems with my code in the fiddle below. These problems are:

- The font awesome icon near the "Name" text is not showing. I wanted to add a little icon for all the fields, but I don't understand why they are not showing
- If the name/creator is too long, the boxes go mad (because of the height) and there will be rows with only one box

Can you help me with some ideas to make the code cleaner? And why aren't the font awesome icons not showing?

You can see a part of my code in the snippet below. Click on expand snippet to view the code in full action. (It's my first time using code snippets, I hope I included all the needed files in the right order, especially for Bootstrap).

Thank you!

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.test = "asdasd";

  $scope.savedGraphSessions = [{
      name: "test",
      creator: "test",
      created: 123456,
      last_use: 1234567
    },
    {
      name: "test",
      creator: "test",
      created: 123456,
      last_use: 1234567
    },
    {
      name: "testtesttesttesttesttest",
      creator: "test",
      created: 123456,
      last_use: 1234567
    },
    {
      name: "test",
      creator: "test",
      created: 123456,
      last_use: 1234567
    },
    {
      name: "test",
      creator: "test",
      created: 123456,
      last_use: 1234567
    },
    {
      name: "test",
      creator: "test",
      created: 123456,
      last_use: 1234567
    }
  ];
}
```

```css
.active-session-box {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
  margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
    <uib-tabset active="active">
      <uib-tab index="0" heading="Continue working from existing session">
        <div style="margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px; max-height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto">
          <div ng-show="savedGraphSessions.length == 0" align="center">
            There are no saved sessions. You can create one from the other tab.
          </div>

          <div class="row row-eq-height" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; width: 100%">
            <div ng-repeat="session in savedGraphSessions | orderBy: 'last_use':true" class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="padding: 5px 2px 0px 2px;">
              <div class="active-session-box">
                <i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Name: {{ session.name }}
                <br> Created by: {{ session.creator || 'Unknown' }}
                <br> Created at: {{ (session.created | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss') || 'Unknown' }}
                <br> Last access: {{ (session.last_use | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss') || 'Unknown' }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you are missing the link to the fontawesome library, or is this just an oversight when adding the code to the question?

Comment: I'm missing the link just in the snippet. In the actual application I have font awesome icons, they are not working just in those custom boxes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to added font-awesome library, just add in your code and more long text you can used `text-overflow`  for hat

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.test = "asdasd";

  $scope.savedGraphSessions = [{
      name: "test",
      creator: "test",
      created: 123456,
      last_use: 1234567
    },
    {
      name: "test",
      creator: "test",
      created: 123456,
      last_use: 1234567
    },
    {
      name: "testtesttesttesttesttest test test very very very very long long long long long long text",
      creator: "test",
      created: 123456,
      last_use: 1234567
    },
    {
      name: "test",
      creator: "test",
      created: 123456,
      last_use: 1234567
    },
    {
      name: "test",
      creator: "test",
      created: 123456,
      last_use: 1234567
    },
    {
      name: "test",
      creator: "test",
      created: 123456,
      last_use: 1234567
    }
  ];
}
```

```css
.active-session-box {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
  margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-8">
    <uib-tabset active="active">
      <uib-tab index="0" heading="Continue working from existing session">
        <div style="margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px; max-height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto">
          <div ng-show="savedGraphSessions.length == 0" align="center">
            There are no saved sessions. You can create one from the other tab.
          </div>

          <div class="row row-eq-height" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; width: 100%">
            <div ng-repeat="session in savedGraphSessions | orderBy: 'last_use':true" class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="padding: 5px 2px 0px 2px;">
              <div class="active-session-box">
                <i class="fa fa-user-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Name: {{ session.name }}
                <br> Created by: {{ session.creator || 'Unknown' }}
                <br> Created at: {{ (session.created | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss') || 'Unknown' }}
                <br> Last access: {{ (session.last_use | date:'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss') || 'Unknown' }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: I'm missing the link just in the snippet. In the actual application I have font awesome icons, they are not working just in those custom boxes. So the missing library isn't the problem.